# CSS Table - Color effect on mouse over in 3 tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 tables with information inside. On mouse over the column and line gets colored. This works perfect for each table individually, but I want it this way:

If my mouse is on field 3 in table 1, not only get the field 3 in table 1 colored, but also in table 2 and table 3.

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td,
th {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
Table 1
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>mouse over on this field</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Table 2
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>should also color this field</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Table 3
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>and this one</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The dupe shows how to set up the logic using _jQuery_, now all you need is to implement this for your cells.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `index()` you can get the row index and column index of the hovered cell and add a class to the corresponding cells in the other tables

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qhu3ytgc/)

```js
const $tables = $('table')

$('td, th').hover(function() {
  const $cell = $(this),
    $row = $cell.parent(),
    $table = $cell.closest('table'),
    cIdx = $cell.index(),
    rIdx = $row.index();

  $tables.not($table).each(function() {
    $(this).find('tr').eq(rIdx).children().eq(cIdx).addClass('activeCell');
  });

}, function() {
  $('.activeCell').removeClass('activeCell')

})
```

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.activeCell,
tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

td,
th {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Table 1
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>mouse over on this field</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Table 2
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>should also color this field</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Table 3
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>and this one</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [Question asking for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277139/question-asking-for-you-to-write-code) ... should be "Vote to close as too broad", not answered, in this case there were a dupe showing the logic.

Comment: @LGSon The duplicate `contains` logic is very different. There may be other indexing versions similar to this but finding them could take as long as throwing this code together did

Comment: My point here weren't about the dupe, it were about _not answer questions asking for code_ ... regarding the dupe, I found it better to close as, than "too broad", as OP could learn from it.